# HackerRank frequency queries

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

need some help or advice, HackerRank's [frequency-queries](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-queries) challenge,
the challenge of this Hackerrank problem is to check if the frequencies of number in your data structure matches the queries.

small integer values, that occupy the first 2 bytes of the integer datatype are fast and passes the test, but for values close to 1.000.000.000 that the occupy the second half of the integer data type are much slower.

the code i made passes 14 of the 15 test.

the code runs in "0.270603 seconds" seconds on my pc for case 8, with 100.000 lines, while reading them from the text  file (input08.txt), but it takes "28.1141 seconds" for test eleven (input11.txt) as also contains 100.000 lines but with values up to 1 billion or 1 to the power of 9 sized values on witch it fails.

it seamed i have build a really lean & fast code, made a custom `main()` function, but ...

the bottleneck seams to be ...

```
does_exist_map(Map &map, int frequency)
```

i tried various ways to loop the map.
what can i do to make it faster?

```
typedef std::map<int, int> Map;

void add_to_map(Map &map, int value){
    /*
    std::cout << "add" << endl;
    if (map.find(value) == map.end()) {
        map[value] = 1;
    }
    else {
        map[value]++;
    }
    */
    if (map.count(value) > 0)
    {
        map[value]++;
    }
    else
    {
        map[value] = 1;
    }
}

void delete_or_update_from_map(Map &map, int value){
    
        if(map[value] > 1){
            map[value]--;
            //std::cout << "found in map and updated: " << value << " value:" << map[value] << endl;
        }
        else{
            //std::cout << "found in map and deleleted: " << value << endl;
            map.erase(value);
        }
    /*
    if (map.find(value) != map.end()) {
        //cout<<"Key (" << value << ") found. Value is: "<<map[value]<<endl;
        if(map[value] > 1){
            map[value]--;
            //std::cout << "found in map and updated: " << value << " value:" << map[value] << endl;
        }
        else{
            //std::cout << "found in map and deleleted: " << value << endl;
            map.erase(value);
        }
    }
    else {
        //std::cout << "not found in map: " << value << endl;
    }
    */
    /*
    if (map.count(value) > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "'hat' Found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "'hat' Not Found" << std::endl;
    }
    */
}

bool does_exist_map(Map &map, int frequency){
    //std::cout << "frequency: " << frequency << endl;
    /*
    or (auto& it : map) {
        //cout << it.first << ' ' << it.second << '\n';
        if(it.second == frequency){
            return true;
        }
    }
    */
    bool itexist = false;
    int sizeMap = map.size();
    auto it = map.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeMap; i++){
        if(it->second == frequency)
        {
            itexist = true;
            break;
            //return true;
        }
        it++;
    }
    /*
    bool itexist = false;
    auto it = map.begin();
    while(it != map.end())
    {
        if(it->second == frequency)
        {
            itexist = true;
            break;
            //return true;
        }
        it++;
    }
    //return false;
    */
    return itexist;
    
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string q_temp;
    getline(cin, q_temp);

    int q = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(q_temp)));

    Map frequencies;

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int input[2] = {0,0};
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> input[j]; 
        }
        //std::cout << "task: " << input[0] << " value: " << input[1] << endl;
        if(input[0] == 1){
            add_to_map(frequencies, input[1]);
        }
        else if(input[0]== 2){
            delete_or_update_from_map(frequencies, input[1]);
        }
        else if(input[0] == 3){
            if(does_exist_map(frequencies, input[1])){
                fout << "1\n";

            }
            else{
                fout << "0\n";
            }
        }  
    }
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a brief summary of the problem that the code solves.

Comment: Hi there, i have updated the question

Comment: Please do not edit the question after there has been an answer, especially don't change the code to the one suggested in the answer. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers): "Do not add an improved version of the code after receiving an answer. Including revised versions of the code makes the question confusing, especially if someone later reviews the newer code."

Comment: @BlameTheBits Ordinarily I'd agree, but the question is still at risk of getting closed. If the question is closed, the answer arrived to early and determining whether it's answer-invalidation gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: ND, do you know why your code fails the 15th test? Is it because the output is wrong or because the time-limit is exceeded?

Comment: @Mast, it fails on test 11 on time-limit, it's a so called corner case where most of the 100.000 values in the array occur only once, but you need to search for one the occurs 2 or more times and you have to iterate the whole map to find that one where the map[key] value is bigger than 1 and it takes to long to find it. for Test 8 that also contains 100.000 it passes the test, it passes 14 of 15 tests. the benefit of map, you can find a key almost instantly, map[...]. i need 2 maps and keep them in sync ... somehow.

Answer (score 3):

## Performance of `std::map`

Well, looking up in a map is a slow operation.

```
if(map[value] > 1){
            map[value]--;
```

is looking up the same thing twice.  Don't do that with maps!

You could write:

```
auto& v= map[value];
if (v>1) --v;
```

Hmm, but you continue with:

```
        else{
            //std::cout << "found in map and deleleted: " << value << endl;
            map.erase(value);
        }
```

So you call the form of `erase` that again looks it up from scratch, even though you already found it.  Note that there is a form of `erase` that takes an iterator instead.

But do you actually have to delete it from the map?  Why not just leave it as zero?  Would that be faster and simpler?

---

I also see you wrote:

```
if (map.count(value) > 0)
    {
        map[value]++;
    }
    else
    {
        map[value] = 1;
    }
```

Same here:  `count` looks it up.  Then you look it up all over again just to increment it, or look up where it should be inserted in order to add it.

Did you know that `map[value]` will automatically add the thing if it wasn't already there?  And, it will initialize the newly created value the same as a static variable would be; that is, zero.  So none of that is necessary.  Just write `++map[value]` and be done with it.

```
   for (auto& it : map) {
        //cout << it.first << ' ' << it.second << '\n';
        if(it.second == frequency){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

OK, you are doing a reverse-lookup.  That's not what maps are good at, and you do a full linear search for the value, using the (slow) pointer-based data structure.  Your three variations of this code doesn't change this, and this first one is the best (other than your missing `const`).  Of course, you are just implementing `std::find` that already exists in the library.

You need a *second* map that indexes the reverse operation.  Be sure to keep them updated in sync.  There is a Boost multi-index map that you can use, too.

Note that every time you update the frequency, you need to change the reverse index, and that can end up being expensive.  If you do lots of adding before any lookups, then don't create the reverse index until you are done adding.  I did something like that recently, and switched from "input mode" to "readout mode" by resorting how I kept the data.

If you are only doing 1 lookup, then sorting/indexing it is more work than you need.

You can instead try speeding up the search my using a Boost `flat_map`.  This keeps everything in a sorted vector instead of a dynamic-memory tree, so traversing it in order will be *much* faster.  The bottleneck is the memory access:  trees of pointers hit cold (uncached) memory at every step, and it can't prefetch because it doesn't know where it's going.  The vector is a contiguous range of memory which means several consecutive entries will be in the same cache row, and if you're scanning through it the CPU will catch on and start prefetching the next block!  **The speed difference on modern architectures is astounding.**  There is an essay on the opening doc page of Boost's flat map that explains in detail.

In the similar task I mentioned earlier, I ended up just using a sorted `std::vector`, so I had full control over sorting, re-sorting, and searching.  Note that you don't have to implement a lot, but can do it all using the supplied Algorithms library:  Use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to either find the element *or* the position where it should be inserted to maintain sort order.

If lookup is clearly done after all addition/removal is performed, and you will have a lot of lookups, then you can re-sort based on the other field.  But since sorting is *n log n* and a single unsorted `find` is order of *n*, if you have fewer than *log n* lookups (as a first approximation) it's faster to just do a linear search.  You might also try using a hash table like `std::unordered_map` but these are also slow for the same reasons explained above, contrary to what is taught in CS classes (because `k` is so extremely large — memory access is the bottleneck).

## other tips

`typedef std::map<int, int> Map;`
Don't use `typedef` anymore.  Use `using` instead, which is more general and works with templates.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> input[j]; 
        }
```

This could be:
`for (auto& x : input) cin>>x;`

```
            if(does_exist_map(frequencies, input[1])){
                fout << "1\n";

            }
            else{
                fout << "0\n";
            }
```

You're just printing the result of the function call as 0 or 1, but you're duplicating entire statements.

```
const bool b = does_exist_map(frequencies, input[1]);
fout << b << '\n';
```

You can control how `bool` values print via [formatting flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).  I think "no alpha" is the default though.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have learned quite a few things, i updated the code and it still works, but i cant use boost, my 8 years old dual 2.5 GHz Intel Celeron, is doing the job quite well, slightly of a quarter of  second with 100.000 values, accept for test 11, "You need a second map that indexes the reverse operation", what do you mean with this?

Comment: i downloaded boost, but there is no way to isolate flat_Map on the fly. HackerRank max support = C14.

Comment: @NaturalDemon I added some more to my post.

Comment: @NaturalDemon _"what do you mean by this?"_  The `map` lets you look up a value based on `first`.  That is, the collection is indexed, or you can consider this to be a key field.  You need another index-like collection that lets you look up a desired value for `second`.  Think about: `for(const auto& rec : map) map2[rec.second]=rec.first;`

Comment: thnx sofar, yeah, i found this "https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/09/11/emulating-boost-multi-index-with-std-containers/" last night and studying how this can be achieved.
I'm struggling with the "Key" thing and temporary pointers. having both key van value as key and pointers as value.

Comment: @NaturalDemon his opening point about creating a dummy Person instead of just finding the email is obsolete; the std containers support that now.  I think that blog code is hard to follow.  Unless you have a great many lookups compared to the number of adds, you are better off just using a sorted vector for adding and unordered search for lookup on `second`.  So don't worry about that blog's code.

Comment: yeah, you're right about that blog code, but it gives a rough idea, I'm fingering out that temporary pointer stuff "Key" and how to replicate and apply  it, i have his code in my compiler and it works, but it's pretty hard to follow on what is going on there. i'm thing about a map and a multimap.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kG0biuut, on my computer i have the rights results, at least they where on my pc. but i changed 'does_exist_map(MultiMap &valuemap, const int frequency)' to find out why it fails on HackerRank, now i'm failing again, but now it does the job in less than a second with 100.000 values. the insertion method is triple checked 'add_to_map', works perfect, as does the 'delete_or_update_from_map' method. on my pc i print the results i na text file and compare them vs output files from HackerRank, it was spot on.

Comment: you just have to find any match on task 3, it doesn't matter if there are multiple. ' Check if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly . If yes, print 1 else 0. '

Comment: If the code works differently on your machine, you may have some "undefined behavior".  Are you compiling with optimization flags?

Comment: i use Qt creator, until now never used them. what are the benefits?

Comment: @NaturalDemon what are you replying to?  What is "them"?

Comment: "optimization flags"

Comment: What are the benefits of turning on optimization?   The code will be _much_ faster and might be smaller as well.